# My Listview doesnt scroll - and I DONT use scrollview

Tags: android, listview, scroll

Firstly I have a tabview with multiple activities, three of which are listviews.

I created the first one - equipment and that worked a treat. I then created the rest by cut/paste the files in eclipse and renaming the files and calling the new files.

Problem - Equipment has stopped scrolling.

Ive even reduced it to its component parts and removed the list prepopulation with a simply options1-5 but it still refuses to move up or down.
IN other windows, even if the list is not fully populated, the window can be grabbed and the contents will scroll up/down and when released will pop back to nromal view at the top of the screen.

Ive compared line by line and for the life of me cant figure out why this is not working.

Code below:

```
    public class harpcsEquipment extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.tab_harp_equipment);
        // Got the entire Equipment list and now we populate the Listview

        String[] listitems = {"Option 1","Option 2","Option 3","Option 4","Option 5"};
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listitems));
    //@Override
    protected void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        // NOW WE ADD DATA TO THE TEMPLATE
        //populateXMLCharacter();
    }
}
```

tab_harp_equipment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the listview was called equiplist but changing to the default name made no difference...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Regards
Jason

I have a lot of code (in this and the cloned classes and the clones work but the parent does not...) I can copy paste the entire lot but since the only difference is the data that is being pasted and the number of fields I am displaying (thus different layout files called in the arrayadapter), but since the basic demo code above doesnt work, Im at a loss...

Comment: When you say default name are you talking about : "android:id="@android:id/list""

Comment: try to add more items on your array of Strings , option1.....option22 for example

Comment: Not all devices allow a list that doesn't need to be scrolled (enough space to fit all of it). Are you using the same device (and version of Android) as before? Some devices won't do the bounce effect you described.

Comment: Camille:yes, houcine: descrition tab has less than screen max lines  and still scrolls, ftm: same device every time. . .

Comment: Added 25 lines amd same issue. - jasonbrisbane

Comment: The program has one tab with three listviews. Onelistview doesnt scroll amd the other two do. . .

Answer (score 0):

OK, better success here after much testing.

I have TWO icons on a home screen (think google plus icon screen if it helps).
Two icons open a tabhost each - there are 8 tabs and fitting them all on one tab is just messy.

All tabs on the first tabhost work. Listviews scroll in them.

All listviews on the second tab do NOT work.
Copying the text:

```
intentE = new Intent().setClass (this, harpcsEquipment.class);
specE = tabHostE.newTabSpec("Equipment").setIndicator("Equipment",
 res.getDrawable(R.drawable.shield)).setContent(intentE);
tabHostE.addTab(specE);
```

from one tabActivity to the next works fine - the equipment listview opens and scrolls.

So the problem is the tabActivity.

Does anyone know why a second tabactivity will not allow a listview to scroll inside it?

Comment: Ok. Fail on my part. The tab xml files had the same id for the tabhost. Thays why it was failing. Hope this helps someone else in the future!!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, Resolved.

TabActivity has a flaw/undocumented feature/etc.
It wont allow you to get full functionality form a second TabActivity inside a program.

So in the calling java program, when I use the intent to call the program that creates the tabhost, I simply putExtra("tab", "1") or putExtra("tab", "2").

Inside the program I simply get the Extra and if tab==1 then load tabhost with one set of Tabhosts intents, and else load it with another set of tabhosts intents.

Damn tabactivity... Whoda thunk it  huh?
Hope this helps someone else in the future.